# Ruby - Adding to each number in array ignoring "AM"/"PM"

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a seemingly simple noobie question, but I can't seem to find the answer though google. I have an array of times (just the hour): `["08 AM", "09 AM", "07 AM", "11 AM", "03 PM", "12 PM"]`. I want to make another array containing each of those times plus 1 hour, so it would output: `["09 AM", "10 AM", "08 AM", "12 PM", "04 PM", "01 PM"]`

Now there is probably a simple way to do this, but the other thing would be dealing with the AM to PM change if I have 11 AM and add an hour to get 12 PM.

Comment: Why the last time is not `01 PM`?

Comment: Sorry about that, you are right - made the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses time parsing and formatting. `require 'time'` is necessary to use the `Time.parse` method.

```
require 'time'
arr = ["08 AM", "09 AM", "07 AM", "11 AM", "03 PM", "12 PM"]

arr.map do |time|
  time = Time.parse(time)
  time += 60 * 60
  time.strftime("%I %p")
end  
# => ["09 AM", "10 AM", "08 AM", "12 PM", "04 PM", "01 PM"]
```

`time += 60 * 60` adds one hour to the time, or `60 minutes x 60 seconds`.

`time.strftime("%I %p")` formats the time using these directives:

- `%I` - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock, zero-padded (`01..12`)
- `%p` - Meridian indicator, uppercase (`AM` or `PM`)

If you like one-liners:

```
arr.map { |t| (Time.parse(t) + 3600).strftime("%I %p") }
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much, I'm learning a lot. Do you know how I can set the output of this to a separate array?

Comment: @ShaneCarroll Sure, just stick `other_array = ` before either of the `arr.map ...` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this.

```
a = ['12 AM', *('01'..'11').map { |a| "#{a} AM" },
     '12 PM', *('01'..'11').map { |a| "#{a} PM" }]
h = Hash[a.zip(a.rotate(1))]
  #=> {"12 AM"=>"01 AM", "01 AM"=>"02 AM", "02 AM"=>"03 AM", "03 AM"=>"04 AM",
  #    "04 AM"=>"05 AM", "05 AM"=>"06 AM", "06 AM"=>"07 AM", "07 AM"=>"08 AM",
  #    "08 AM"=>"09 AM", "09 AM"=>"10 AM", "10 AM"=>"11 AM", "11 AM"=>"12 PM",
  #    "12 PM"=>"01 PM", "01 PM"=>"02 PM", "02 PM"=>"03 PM", "03 PM"=>"04 PM",
  #    "04 PM"=>"05 PM", "05 PM"=>"06 PM", "06 PM"=>"07 PM", "07 PM"=>"08 PM",
  #    "08 PM"=>"09 PM", "09 PM"=>"10 PM", "10 PM"=>"11 PM", "11 PM"=>"12 AM"}
```

If

```
arr = ["08 AM", "09 AM", "07 AM", "11 AM", "03 PM", "12 PM"]
```

then

```
arr.map { |t| h[t] }
  #=> ["09 AM", "10 AM", "08 AM", "12 PM", "04 PM", "01 PM"]
```

or

```
h.values_at(*arr)
  #=> ["09 AM", "10 AM", "08 AM", "12 PM", "04 PM", "01 PM"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1- use time.parse to parse your string to time object
2- add hour to your time object
3- convert it back to string using time.strftime
```